# Treat the text as blocks

Tags: xml, bash, shell

I have following block of text:

```xml
<item>
    <link>test1</link>
    <title>ABC1</title>
    <Date>Tue, 07 Jun 2023</Date>
</item>
<item>
    <link>test3</link>
    <title>ABC3</title>
    <Date>Fri, 27 Jun 2022</Date>
</item>
<item>
    <link>test2</link>
    <title>ABC2</title>
    <Date>Mon, 05 Jun 2021</Date>
</item>
```

And I am trying to get the following format:

```
Tue, 07 Jun 2023 <item> 
Tue, 07 Jun 2023     <link>test1</link>
Tue, 07 Jun 2023     <title>ABC1</title>
Tue, 07 Jun 2023     <Date>Tue, 07 Jun 2023</Date>
Tue, 07 Jun 2023 </item>
Fri, 27 Jun 2022 <item>
Fri, 27 Jun 2022     <link>test3</link>
Fri, 27 Jun 2022     <title>ABC3</title>
Fri, 27 Jun 2022     <Date>Fri, 27 Jun 2022</Date>
Fri, 27 Jun 2022 </item>
Mon, 05 Jun 2021 <item>
Mon, 05 Jun 2021     <link>test2</link>
Mon, 05 Jun 2021     <title>ABC2</title>
Mon, 05 Jun 2021     <Date>Mon, 05 Jun 2021</Date>
Mon, 05 Jun 2021 </item>
```

I know how to select the desired date from text, this can be done with:

```bash
grep -oE "[A-Z][a-z][a-z],.*2[0-9][0-9][0-9]" ./file
```

but no idea how to insert then the extracted date in a block of text (starting with `<item>` to `</item>`).
It looks like I need to treat the text as blocks. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: It can probably be done using `sed` or `awk` but it looks more like a task for a more advanced programming or scripting language.

Answer (score 2):

This feels 'fragile', and you should definitely consider using a scripting language / parser to handle this type of data, but you *could* do it using awk, e.g.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[><]"} {a[++b] = $0} /Date/ {c = $3} /\/item/ {for (i=1; i<=length(a); i++) {print c, a[i]}; delete a; b = c = 0}' test.txt
Tue, 07 Jun 2023 <item>
Tue, 07 Jun 2023     <link>test1</link>
Tue, 07 Jun 2023     <title>ABC1</title>
Tue, 07 Jun 2023     <Date>Tue, 07 Jun 2023</Date>
Tue, 07 Jun 2023 </item>
Fri, 27 Jun 2022 <item>
Fri, 27 Jun 2022     <link>test3</link>
Fri, 27 Jun 2022     <title>ABC3</title>
Fri, 27 Jun 2022     <Date>Fri, 27 Jun 2022</Date>
Fri, 27 Jun 2022 </item>
Mon, 05 Jun 2021 <item>
Mon, 05 Jun 2021     <link>test2</link>
Mon, 05 Jun 2021     <title>ABC2</title>
Mon, 05 Jun 2021     <Date>Mon, 05 Jun 2021</Date>
Mon, 05 Jun 2021 </item>
```

---

Nicer formatting and some comments:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FS = "[><]"    # set the field separator to either < or >
}

{
    a[++b] = $0    # load every line from the block into a numbered array
}

/Date/ {           # if the line contains Date, grab column 3 (the date)
    c = $3
}

/\/item/ {         # for /item line, print Date then all of the array
    for (i = 1; i <= length(a); i++) {
        print c, a[i]
    }
    delete a       # delete the array for the next <item> ... <\item> block
    b = c = 0      # reset variables for the next <item> ... <\item> block
}' test.txt
Tue, 07 Jun 2023 <item>
Tue, 07 Jun 2023     <link>test1</link>
Tue, 07 Jun 2023     <title>ABC1</title>
Tue, 07 Jun 2023     <Date>Tue, 07 Jun 2023</Date>
Tue, 07 Jun 2023 </item>
Fri, 27 Jun 2022 <item>
Fri, 27 Jun 2022     <link>test3</link>
Fri, 27 Jun 2022     <title>ABC3</title>
Fri, 27 Jun 2022     <Date>Fri, 27 Jun 2022</Date>
Fri, 27 Jun 2022 </item>
Mon, 05 Jun 2021 <item>
Mon, 05 Jun 2021     <link>test2</link>
Mon, 05 Jun 2021     <title>ABC2</title>
Mon, 05 Jun 2021     <Date>Mon, 05 Jun 2021</Date>
Mon, 05 Jun 2021 </item>
```

Answer (score 1):

A tricky bit of perl:

```bash
perl -0777 -pe '
    s{(<item>.+?<Date>(.+?)</Date>.+?</item>)}   # capture a block and its date
     {
        $date = $2;                              # cache the date
        ($block = $1) =~ s/^/$date /mg;          # add the date at start of each line
        $block                                   # return the modified block
     }sge'
```

perl option `-0777` means the entire input is slurped into the default variable.

`s///` flags

- `g` means global search-and-replace
- `m` means `^` matches at the start of the string, or after a newline
- `s` means `.` can match a newline
- `e` means the replacement string is evaluated as code.

Answer (score 0):

[TXR](https://nongnu.org.txr) solution. First a simple one which matches the data rather exactly:

```
@(repeat)
<item>
@line1
@line2
    <Date>@date</Date>
</item>
@  (output)
@date <item>
@date @line1
@date @line2
@date     <Date>@date</Date>
@date </item>
@  (end)
@(end)
```

```
$ txr blocks.txr blocks.xml
Tue, 07 Jun 2023 <item>
Tue, 07 Jun 2023     <link>test1</link>
Tue, 07 Jun 2023     <title>ABC1</title>
Tue, 07 Jun 2023     <Date>Tue, 07 Jun 2023</Date>
Tue, 07 Jun 2023 </item>
Fri, 27 Jun 2022 <item>
Fri, 27 Jun 2022     <link>test3</link>
Fri, 27 Jun 2022     <title>ABC3</title>
Fri, 27 Jun 2022     <Date>Fri, 27 Jun 2022</Date>
Fri, 27 Jun 2022 </item>
Mon, 05 Jun 2021 <item>
Mon, 05 Jun 2021     <link>test2</link>
Mon, 05 Jun 2021     <title>ABC2</title>
Mon, 05 Jun 2021     <Date>Mon, 05 Jun 2021</Date>
Mon, 05 Jun 2021 </item>
```

More general: the blocks can be any number of lines long, using any tag (not only `item`):

```
@(repeat)
<@tag>
@  (collect)
@line
@  (last)
    <Date>@date</Date>
</@tag>
@  (end)
@  (output)
@date <@tag>
@  (repeat)
@date @line
@  (end)
@date     <Date>@date</Date>
@date </@tag>
@  (end)
@(end)
```

With correct syntax highlighting in Vim you can easily tell apart literal text from directives and variables:

[image: Second solution screenshot with syntax highlighting]